# How change jquery ui resizable options dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery ui resizable control to resize image.

I want resize the image with aspect ratio.

but it is now working properly.

Here is the script:

```
$("#cover_page_image_change").resizable({ aspectRatio:true});
```

Hence I think if we can change the maxHeight and maxWidth options of it then it may possible.
We will provide these option dynamically by calculating the real aspect ration.

Is any one know how to do it?

Or for aspect ratio what should i do?
I am using jquery ui 1.9 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way you can provide width and height

```
 var coverpagee=$('#cover_page_image_change');
 var val=2;
 coverpage.css({
 width:target.width() * val,
 height:target.height() * val});
```

Rather than using `val` you can use any variable whose value get assigned dynamically.